# Measuring Smoothness of a Grayscale image

Tags: python, matlab, opencv, image-processing, scikit-image

For suppose, I have 2 images like below rough edges image and some noisy pixels all around the structure of image

[image]

I have converted the Image like this with some pre-processing and removed almost all the noisy pixels.

[image]

I would like to calculate a smoothness metric for the image. In order to prove that we have less noisy pixels inside the processed image. Any metric to calculate this. I had tried the Laplacian filter and calculating the variance(Didn't work).

Note: Noisy pixels indicate the pixels between the 0 and 255.

Comment: There is no difference in smoothness in your two images. All the same features are there. It is only a matter of how thick the lines are.

Comment: I did blur, erosion and dilation. I kept the kernel size 1*1 for blur as I'm losing info if I do have big kernel. If you clearly get a note of all the pixels inside each image, removing the pixels with the maximum intensity and see, you will see noisy pixels.

Answer (score 2):

How about Sum of Squared Errors between the image and its black and white equivalent:

```
SSE = sum(sum(((I>0.5)-I).^2));
```

Since this noise has the characteristics of the Salt and Pepper noise, the application of the median filter reduces it even more. However, the median filter slightly alters the thinned image.
Another possible improvement could be the black and white filter itself. Although this filter completely eliminates the noise, its will also sharpen soft edges.
The following image demonstrates the effect of these filters, along with errors in their resulting images.
[image]

Comment: How is the black and white equivalent converted that way? Can I get some reference to understand this?

Comment: @Bharath_Raja, An intensity threshold is all you need to perform a B&W filter. `(I>0.5)` in the code returns an binary image in which pixels with intensities greater than 0.5 will become 1 (`true`), and the rest of them will become 0. If intensities are in 0..255 range you can use `(I>127). These codes are in MATLAB btw.